# Is Louise doomed, or can I save her?

Tags: vampyr

Currently on Chapter 4, and while exploring around some of the abandoned houses in the West End, I found a house broken open with blood stains everywhere. On walking in, my character remarked on the blood, and a quest called "Like Father, Like Daughter" was added to my log with an accompanying 'citizen in peril' (the head with an exclamation point) icon on my map in a very out-of-the-way location - the kind that means you need to save them *tonight* or they're gone for good.

Looking it up, it seems the character is Louise Teasdale and she's trapped in the sewers. I really want to rescue her, but all the game guides seem to suggest I should be exploring the sewers during Chapter 5 and first encountering her then.

This leaves me with two questions: A) can I explore the West End sewers now and rescue her in Chapter 4? and B) if I can't, will progressing the game until chapter 5 without manually resting count as going to a new night (and cause her death), or can I make it to Chapter 5 and rescue her then?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I did some more in-depth exploring in my game this evening, and can now confirm that **yes, it is possible to rescue Louise in chapter 4**.

It's significantly more difficult, because the quest marker for Louise is nowhere near the entrance to the West End sewers (which is located in the northwest-most corner of the West End park, right at the corner of the map) so some exploring is necessary, and because going through the sewers in chapter 4 will have you fight a Vulkod miniboss whose health and damage seem calibrated for players in chapter 5. However, with some perseverance I was able to find and save her in the sewers and complete the sidequest before chapter 5.

Additionally, the transition from chapter 4 to chapter 5 didn't force me back to my Pembroke bed, so I suspect I could have also successfully saved her by proceeding to chapter 5 so long as I didn't manually rest at any point.